# Error "errorCode=1" (HMS Core FIDO error) is reported when the 3D facial authentication function is used

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

The following error is reported when I use the 3D facial authentication function on a device running EMUI 10.0: errorCode=1

```
// Cancellation Signal
CancellationSignal cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

FaceManager faceManager = new FaceManager(this);

// Checks whether 3D facial authentication can be used.
int errorCode = faceManager.canAuth();
if (errorCode != 0) {
resultTextView.setText("");
showResult("Can not authenticate. errorCode=" + errorCode);
return;
}
```

Operation device: P40 Pro or Honor 30 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3D facial authentication function depends on the device hardware. Currently, it can only be used on Mate 20 Pro and Mate 30 Pro devices.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Although the above answer is correct but i would highly recommend you to go through below error list and see for yourself what exact reason this code is providing.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/facemanager_x-0000001050418949-V5

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/bioauthn_facemanager-0000001050180181-V5

The exact explanation of your error is:

**public static final int FACE_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE**

Return value of the **errorCode** parameter in the **onAuthError** method of **BioAuthnCallback** after the auth method is called; return value of the canAuth API: 1

No authentication hardware is available. Try again later.